# Check if Element exists in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to check if an element exists in Selenium, and if it does, assign it to a name.

Right now I have something that looks like this:

```
IWebElement size9 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[data-value*='09.0']"));
```

However, when that element that has the value of 9 does not exist, it returns an error. Is there a way I can check to see if it exists, or something of that sort?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several options. I recommend these.

1. Create a method or web driver extension.

```
public static IWebElement FindElementIfExists(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
{
    var elements = driver.FindElements(by);
    return (elements.Count >=1) ? elements.First() : null;
}

// Usage
var element = driver.FindElementIfExists(By.CssSelector("a[data-value*='09.0']"));
```

2. Count the element, get it if there are 1 or more elements.

```
By by = By.CssSelector("a[data-value*='09.0']");
var element = driver.FindElements(by).Count >= 1 ? driver.FindElement(by) : null;
```

Then you can check `if(element != null) { ... }`

Comment: What kind of programming language is that? Looks like `Java` mixed with `JavaScript`. Does `Java` have a new feature like auto-detecting a type of a variable? Something like `auto` in `C++`? And what does `this` keyword near the type of the first argument mean?

Comment: @ibodi The question was for C#, so I'm pretty sure this is C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
//Method :
public static bool IsElementPresent_byCssSelector(string elementName)
{
    try { Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementName)); }
    catch (NoSuchElementException) { return false; }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { return false; }
    return true;
}

//Usage :
var test = driver.IsElementPresent_byCssSelector("a[data-value*='09.0']");

if(test)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Hmm the method did not get attached. Updated the above.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Dazed's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755103/), I do a little modification to pass any selector.

```
//Method :
public bool ElementExists(By by)
{
     try 
     { 
         Driver.FindElement(by); 
     }
     catch (NoSuchElementException) 
     { 
          return false; 
     }
     catch (StaleElementReferenceException) 
     { 
          return false; 
     }
     return true;
}

//Usage:
if (ElementExists(By.XPath("...")))
   ...
if (ElementExists(By.Id("...")))
   ...
if (ElementExists(By.CssSelector("...")))
   ...
```